# Slowing down scrolling in IMWheel for one of the two mice

Tags: mouse

I have two mice. I want to apply the settings to only one of them. On the site → https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/IMWheel I only see settings for selected windows, not for the selected mouse.

```
xinput --list      
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ 2.4G Mouse                                id=8    [slave  pointer  (For ID 8 mouse I want to set IMWheel to slow down scrolling. If it is possible?2)]
⎜   ↳ Lenovo TrackPoint Keyboard II Mouse       id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

I did

```
".*"
None,       Up,     Up,     1
None,       Down,   Down,   1
```

Currently, I have the slowdown of scrolling set to very slow for the mouse and for the second mouse on the keyboard.
I want to set the slowdown of scrolling only for the mouse ID: 8 If it is possible?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suspect the answer is "no", as IMWheel does not use XInput to receive the original input events – it uses only the X11 "core input" events, which cannot distinguish between multiple sources. (That's what the "virtual core pointer" in `xinput` refers to.)

Rewriting IMWheel to use XInput might require a bit of work (its latest release actually predates the current XInput2 by several years).

If you cannot find an XInput property for this (in `xinput list-props "2.4G Mouse"`), it might be easier to build something similar using modern tools that are built on evdev events, for example [interception-tools](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/tools) to rate-limit EV_REL/REL_WHEEL (relative wheel motion) events, or [mxk](http://welz.org.za/projects/mxk).